# Oracle - Selecting from remote database taken from PL/SQL parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a procedure to merge two tables across different database instances. The DB_FROM and the DB_TO are given as parameters to the procedure. Everything else is hardcoded.

```
PROCEDURE MERGE_TABLE_1(DB_FROM, DB_TO) AS
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO TABLE_1@DB_TO DSTN
      USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1@DB_FROM) SRC
      ON (DSTN.ID = SRC.ID)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
END MERGE_TABLE_1
```

I get the below error when I attempt to compile

```
Error(1): ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object 
TABLE_1@DB_TO ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it will not work that way. You cannot use variables as table names, column names or db link names in static SQL. You can achieve what you want using [dynamic sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011):

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
 'MERGE INTO TABLE_1@' || DB_TO || ' DSTN
  USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1@' || DB_FROM || ') SRC
  ON (DSTN.ID = SRC.ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ...';
```